# Syslog doesn't send messages over UDP

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

I want to send logs to a remote server using rsyslog. Somehow rsyslog doesn't send any messages.

This is my config (I am using the new syntax):

```
template(name="myTemplate"
    type="string"
    string="%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogfacility-text%.%syslogseverity-text%")

local7.* {
    action(type="ofwd" target="192.168.1.10" port="514" protocol="udp")
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have any rules in place that say *"log to local7"*? As this isn't a standard log destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the *message* in your template. I am not sure though, if it would be sent anyways - just without a message - or if it would be discarded.

To solve that, just append **%msg%** to the template string:

```
template(name="myTemplate"
    type="string"
    string="%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogfacility-text%.%syslogseverity-text% %msg%")
```

The reason why you're logs aren't being forwarded though, is because you're using the incorrect *module* name in the action. It should be `omfwd` instead of `ofwd`:

```
local7.* {
    action(type="omfwd" target="192.168.1.10" port="514" protocol="udp")
}
```